# Firefox displays question marks(?) instead of Unicode Text in ASP.net Textbox , OK in IE 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, unicode

We used  Asp.Net Textbox in Application.In the Textbox user can Enter the unicode

character(Marathi/Devnagari).when I Browse this Application  with IE 8.0 it works fine, it

displays the Unicode characters in Textbox.

But whenever I browse this Application with Mozila FireFox(V.20.0.1). It displays Question

Marks(?) Instead of Unicode character(Marathi/Devnagari).

I implemented  the code in web.config file like this:

```
 <system.web>
 <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8"
  requestEncoding="utf-8"
  responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
 </system.web>
```

But it is not working,

I also tried follwing code in page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="search.aspx.cs" 
  Inherits="search"   ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

This Code does not work at all.

VS2005
Framework:2.0
language:C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the server sends a content-type (text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1) via the HTTP response headers and in that case that content type prevails. The page code is saved with an UTF-8 byte order mark (ï»¿) that you see in this case.

http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.valuevisionglasses.co.uk&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=HEAD&uak=0

---

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#AddType

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue is solved, I used the Meta tag in header section in following way:
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>